# How to make the precision of float numbers the same using Javascript

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

I have two float numbers in Javascript with high and lower precision (not known in advance) for example:

```
1545.165 
12.15364613
```

How can I round the high precision number to the same precision as lower precision number?
In our case to

```
12.154
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrangle around with the `toFixed()` function.

**Syntax:** `<number>.toFixed(precision)`

For example:

`12.15364613.toFixed(3)` gives `12.154`

But to make it work in your case you want to do something like this:

*Warning* untested code, I only meant to give you a general idea of how this can be done, of course the code below can be improved.

```
var num1 = 12.15364613;
var num1Str = (12.15364613).toString();
var num1Precision = parseInt(num1Str.substring(num1Str.indexOf('.')).length - 1);

var num2 = 12.154;
var num2Str = (12.154).toString();
var num2Precision = parseInt(num2Str.substring(num2Str.indexOf('.')).length - 1);

if(num1Precision > num2Precision){
    num1 = num1.toFixed(num2Precision);
} else{
    num2 = num2.toFixed(num1Precision);
}
```

Comment: How do you know that precision is equal to 3 ?

Comment: @ФилиппЦветков You choose what precision you find useful.

Comment: @Kroltan I think OP means something else with precision, but I also don't know what.

Comment: The precision is not known in advance. I put the precise numbers as examples

Comment: Better. But there is no any native number function to get precision without converting it to string?

Comment: @ФилиппЦветков I don't think it's possible because indexOf only works with strings. But this is a pretty neat solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Pure Math Solution**

In order to get precision of unknown number (variable) you can use such a function:

```
function getPrecision(x) {
    // i < 10 - just to avoid infinite looping
    // (which may occur if x is a real number like PI)
    // x - Math.floor(x) + (x < 0? 1 : 0) is a fractional part of x
    for (var i = 0; i < 10 && x - Math.floor(x) + (x < 0? 1 : 0) > 0; i++, x *= 10) ;
    return i;
}
```

So the code should like this:

```
// array of given numbers:
aVals = [1545.165, 12.15364613];
// array of numbers' precisions:
var aPre = aVals.map(getPrecision);
// find the least precision:
var minPre = Math.min.apply(null, aPre);

// result array of fixed numbers with the same precision:
var aValsFixed = aVals.map(function(v) { return v.toFixed(minPre); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
var number = 1.2333445454;

var n = number.toFixed(3);

alert(n);
```

Comment: Why you fixed precision to 3?

Comment: The precision is not known in advance. I put the precise numbers as examples